# Why isolate scope "@" and $apply don't work as expected

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I've been studying AngularJS and in particular saw the video:

http://www.thinkster.io/pick/IgQdYAAt9V/angularjs-directives-talking-to-controllers

This video presents an example of a directive talking to a controller which I've modified a bit to try and understand if one could also use an isolate scope to get a similar result. Consider an HTML snippet such as:

```
<div enter="loadMoreTweets()">Roll Over This</div>
```

and an Angular controller and directive defined as:

```
app.controller('scopeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
        alert("loading more tweets");
    }
}).directive('enter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {enter: "@"},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("mouseenter", function() {
                //scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
                scope.$apply(scope.enter);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Rolling over the DIV causes no errors and has no effect.

If I comment out the isolate scope and use the commented line in the element.bind() rather than the reference to `scope.enter` then rolling over the DIV causes the `alert()` to display as expected.

Question: If the "@" isolate scope creates a one-way binding between the attribute's value and the scope's property then I would have expected that `scope.enter == attrs.enter`. Clearly this isn't true. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that '@' is a one way data binding but it's passed always as a `string`

```
scope: {              // set up directive's isolated scope
  name: "@",          // name var passed by value (string, one-way)
  age: "=",           // age var passed by reference (two-way)
  showName: "&"       // passed as function
}
```

> The at sign "@" indicates this variable is passed by value. The directive receives a string that contains the value passed in from the parent scope. The directive may use it but it cannot change the value in the parent scope (it is isolated).

Comment: Thanks. I do understand but that's why the behavior surprised me. In the markup enter="loadMoreTweets()" specifies a string, at least it looks like a string because it's enclosed in quotation marks. So then the isolate scope should, I thought pick up the same string of characters so the isolate scope's property, "enter" would then have the string value "loadMoreTweets()". This seemed to me to be identical to the string attrs.enter which would also contain a string of characters that are specified in the markup. It seemed that both would be strings and both have the same value.